# unlinked account error on youtube api

Tags: youtube-api

I try and call this endpoint with an access token from auth2:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?access_token={mytoken}&alt=json

and when I use it for a user with a channel on youtube it works fine. though, when I try to use it for an "unlinked account" user (no channel on youtube yet) it returns me this html response

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>User authentication required.</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <H1>User authentication required.</H1>
    <H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
```

From what I've searched I saw that I should use v2.1 instead of v2.0 and so I tried to add header to the request "GData-Version=2.1", though nothing seem to change in the response. Still same error. Also, tried to add querystring "&v=2.1" and still nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the v=2.1 did work at the end.